# Sencha touch: Ext.List different item template for each list item

Tags: list, templates, sencha-touch

I'm trying to implement an application using the Sencha touch framework. At a certain point, my application has to show a list of generic item. The template to use to rapresent the i-th item depends on the type of item. Is it possible to do that in sencha?
Thank you in advance for any help! Cheers.

Comment: I have same question.. have you found any solution..

Answer (score 2):

See [This](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?151694-Can-I-have-dinamic-different-List-itemTpl)

Comment: Including an external reference to a well documented source is appreciated here on Stack Overflow but it is important to include in your answer the most important/relevant snippets from the external source and give context as to how to answer the question because if that link goes dead (server goes down, etc), then your answer becomes useless.